# What is causing my first-chance (stack overflow) exception in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, exception, stack-overflow

I have a QComboBox which should be updated on CurrentTextChanged. I have created the following connect statement so that the QComboBox fires the onFilterComboBoxCurrentTextChanged slot:

```
connect(m_viewController->getFilterWindow()->getFilterComboBox(), &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, this, &MainController::onFilterComboBoxCurrentTextChanged);
```

**clearAndAddDICOMTagsToShownTagsListWidget** causes the following errors. How can I solve this?

```
void MainController::onFilterComboBoxCurrentTextChanged(QString filterName)
{
    m_viewController->clearAndAddFilterNamesToFilterComboBox(m_fileController->loadFilterNamesFromConfigFile());
}

QStringList FileController::loadFilterNamesFromConfigFile()
{
    QSettings settings(QDir::toNativeSeparators("C:\\HelloWorld\\Config\\Filter.cfg"), QSettings::IniFormat);
    QStringList filtersNames = settings.childGroups();
    return filtersNames;
}

    void ViewController::clearAndAddFilterNamesToFilterComboBox(QStringList filterNames)
{
    m_filterWindow.getFilterComboBox()->clear();
    m_filterWindow.getFilterComboBox()->addItems(filterNames);
}

QListWidget* FilterWindow::getShownTagsListWidget()
{
    return ui.shownTagsListWidget;
}
```

> First-chance exception at 0x777EAFC0 (ntdll.dll) in DoseView.exe:
>   0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x002C2FFC).
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x777EAFC0 (ntdll.dll) in DoseView.exe:
>   0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x002C2FFC).

[image]

Comment: Wee need to see `clearAndAddFilterNamesToFilterComboBox` method. Most likely, you are causing `currentTextChanged` signal to be emited inside the function which results in recursive call of the slot which causes stack overflow.

Comment: @Jaa-c Sorry, I pasted the wrong function into the question :). I've updated the code

Comment: @Jaa-c How can I solve this? Unfortunately I don't fully understand why it causes a recursive call -> stack overflow

Comment: @Engo It happens because `onFilterComboBoxCurrentTextChanged` calls `clearAndAddFilterNamesToFilterComboBox`, which changes the text in the combo box, which causes a call to `onFilterComboBoxCurrentTextChanged`, and so on. Why are you repopulating the combo box every time it changes?

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you for your great explanation!

Comment: I found it hard to choose the best answer :S. molbdnilo's comment helped me the most understanding the cause. I think Mehrdad deserves it because he provided a code sample... Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy fix is to block signals before updating combo box's items. Something like this :

```
void MainController::onFilterComboBoxCurrentTextChanged(QString filterName) {
combobox->blockSignals(true); 
m_viewController->clearAndAddFilterNamesToFilterComboBox(m_fileController->loadFilterNamesFromConfigFile());
combobox->blockSignals(false);
}
```

But I believe you should be able to prevent it by a better design of your code.

Comment: You were right about a "better design". I've refactored my code and I didn't need any blocksignals :)

Answer (score 2):

The recursion looks like this:

1. Text changes in combobox
2. You call clear (it causes text change)
3. Go back to 1 - recursion ready.

If you need to stop signal propagation when you perform your operation call `blockSignals` on your combobox object. However, I would really rethink your app logic. I work with Qt a lot, and didn't need to use blockSignals a lot.

Comment: You were right about a "rethink your app logic". I've refactored my code and I didn't need any blocksignals :)